# How to get the names of nodes with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, nodes

Say that I have this xml:

```
<Parent>
    <Child>
        <ChildOfChild>
        </ChildOfChild>
    </Child>
    <Child2>
    </Child2>
</Parent>
```

I would like to get the name of the nodes?, I know I can get the name of the parent with:

```
XDocument xd;
String test;
test = xd.Root.Name.LocalName; // test would contain "Parent"
```

But how do I get the name of the children?

As I can get the next child with `xd.Root.FirstNode` but I cant find any property or similar to get the name of the child, in this case **Child**

Comment: XDocument, added it to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xd.Root.FirstNode` returns the first child node of the root element, which is not necessary an element (could be a comment for example, which don't have names).

Try the following:

```
xd.Root.Elements().First().Name.LocalName;
```